# str_replace on an embedded css style

Tags: php, preg-replace, background-image, str-replace

Is it possible to do a str_replace or preg_replace on an embedded style? I've tried various options with little luck and I'm not sure what I'm missing.

I have a  tag on page with a bunch of CSS many of which contain classes with relative background paths for example:

```
background: url("/wcsstore/comp/en_GB/header.jpg") no-repeat; background-position: center center; height: 200px; max-width: 1200px; margin: 0 auto 40px;
```

I'm trying to replace this path to an absolute path with the following code but can't seem to target the CSS on the page.

```
$replaceThis = 'url(\"/wcsstore/"';
str_replace('/wcsstore/', 'http://****.com/nimrod/wcsstore/', $replaceThis);
```

Thanks.

P.S It is not possible in this case purpose for me to target individual classes. This is a snippet included in a header template to be executed across 1000+ pages.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to assign the new value to a variable:

```
$css ='background: url("/wcsstore/comp/en_GB/header.jpg") no-repeat; background-position: center center; height: 200px; max-width: 1200px; margin: 0 auto 40px;';
$css = str_replace('/wcsstore/', 'http://****.com/nimrod/wcsstore/', $css);
echo "$css\n";
```

**Output:**

```
background: url("http://****.com/nimrod/wcsstore/comp/en_GB/header.jpg") no-repeat; background-position: center center; height: 200px; max-width: 1200px; margin: 0 auto 40px;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I just tried to execuse that but it only seems to echo the path and doesn't actually execute all the changes on the document. Am I missing something really simple? (PHP Newbie)

Comment: Thank for you for your reply really appreciate the help. I just updated the code to your edited suggestion but unfortunately its still just printing out the path and not executing the changes in the embedded <style>.

Comment: @user6583984:Please, edit your question and add the full real string you want to modify, and expected result.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my original question - hopefully this helps.

Comment: Thank you Toto. I still think I'm missing something obvious as it's just not executing on my document to change the paths. I've created this test document here to ensure theres nothing conflicting somehow..

https://pastebin.com/u8VH2DhD

Please do let me know if you have a way of me donating for your help its really appreciated!